# WCF Rest - what are the best practices?

Tags: wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api

Just started my first WCF rest project and would like some help on what are the best practices for using REST.

I have seen a number of tutorials and there seems to be a number of ways to do things...for example if doing a POST, I have seen some tutorials which are setting HttpStatusCodes (OK/Errors etc), and other tutorials where they are just returning strings which contain result of the operation.

At the end of the day, there are 4 operations and surely there must be a guide that says if you are doing a GET, do it this way, etc and with a POST, do this...

Any help would be appreciated.

JD

Comment: REST best practices: dont use WCF REST. Just avoid it like a plague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## UPDDATE

Use ASP.NET Web API.

---

OK I left the comment `REST best practices: dont use WCF REST. Just avoid it like a plague` and I feel like I have to explain it.

One of the fundamental flaws of the WCF is that it is concerned only with the **Payload**. For example `Foo` and `Bar` are the payloads here.

```
[OperationContract]
public Foo Do(Bar bar)
{
    ...
}
```

This is one of the tenants of WCF so that no matter what the **transport** is, we get the **payload** over to you.

But what it ignore is the `context/envelope` of the call which in many cases transport specific - so a lot of the context get's lost. In fact, HTTP's power lies in its context not payload and back in the earlier versions of WCF, there was no way to get the client's IP Address in `netTcpBinding` and WCF team were adamant that they cannot provide it. I cannot find the page now but remember reading the comments and the MS guys just said this is not supported.

Using WCF REST, you lose the flexibility of HTTP in expressing yourself clearly (and they had to budge it later) in terms of:

- HTTP Status code
- HTTP media types
- ETag, ...

The new Web API, Glenn Block is working addresses this issue by encapsulating the payload in the context:

```
public HttpResponse<Foo> Do(HttpRequest<Bar> bar) // PSEUDOCODE
{
    ...
}
```

But to my test this is not perfect and I personally prefer to use frameworks such as Nancy or even plain ASP NET MVC to expose web API.

Comment: There are other issues in REST that do not normally affect conventional web apps in terms of content type negotiation, JSONP and OData support, etc that you could have to hand roll in MVC (not sure about Nancy as I've not used it) that are built in to the Web API

Comment: @RichardBlewett ASP NET MVC is not just por building conventional web apps.

Comment: @Aliostad : :) Now I am more confused. I thought the replies would be like Richards and it would be a case of setting StatusCodes etc. We are about to start a WCF project and would you say go with ASP.net MVC rather than just WCF Rest (even though there are no views and we are just returning JSON data)?

Comment: @Aliostad : Wouldn't I be doing the same (i.e. setting HTTP statusCodes etc) if I went the ASP MVC route?

Comment: @JD. Yes! That is exactly what I am saying (Drop WCF RESR and use ASP NET MVC instead) although NancyFx is a purer framework but not sure if your company will like it. The new Web API stuff is OK but not final so perhaps you cannot use it.

Comment: @JD. Setting Status code requires accessing `WebOperationContext.Current` which is ugly while in ASP NET MVC you return `HttpStatusResult` which is 10x better.

Comment: http://servicestack.net/ looks like a serious/better alternative for WCF. Works together with asp.net mvc.

Comment: In .NET 4 you can throw a WebFaultException rather than using WebOperationContext and there are helpers for things like NotFound and Created. However, I would use the Web API rather than the existing infrastructure. And I know MVC isn't just for creating conventional websites - but REST requires more than using verbs URIs and returning different content types - for these extra things you have to hand roll the support in MVC whereas its built into the Web API

Comment: @RichardBlewett : Thanks Richard for you views. I just need to make the right decision and you guys have highlighted things I was not even aware of. You mentioned the "existing infrastructure". Can you highlight what you mean by this? Do you mean not use MVC? Also, where can I learn what are the best practices/rules if I go WCF Rest?

Comment: @Aliostad : You mentioned "WebOperationContext.Current" was ugly? Could you tell me why? Is it from a testing point of view (i.e. mocking it out?). Any information you can give will help me convince the team why we have chosen which technology. Thanks.

Comment: @JD. since it is not natural and yes, you are right since it is impossible to unit test. This was provided just as a hack really.

Comment: @AlioStad: Thank you with all the information you have provided. I did not realize there was so much to REST that I need to first understand before I can even think which is the right framework. Clearly you have highlighted that WCF Rest is not something viable at first glance.

Comment: @JD by existing infrastructure I mean the current .NET 4.0 bits - the are usable in simple cases but if you want a fuller embracing of HTTP and you want support for common REST idioms out of the box then the new Web API is definitely worth considering

Answer (score 6):

There are some basic rules when using the different HTTP verbs that come from the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.htmln)

GET: This is a pure read operation. Invocation must not cause state change in the service. The response to a GET may be delivered from cache (local, proxy, etc) depending on caching headers

DELETE: Used to delete a resource

There is sometimes some confusion around PUT and POST - which should be used when? To answer that you have to consider idempotency - whether the operation can be repeated without affecting service state - so for example setting a customer's name to a value can be repeated multiple times without further state change; however, if I am incrementing a customer's bank balance this cannot be safely be repeated without further state change on the service. The first is said to be idempotent the second is not

PUT: Non-delete state changes that are idempotent

POST: Non-delete state changes that are not idempotent

REST embraces HTTP - therefore failures should be communicated using HTTP status codes. 200 for success, 201 for creation and the service should return a URI for the new resource using the HTTP location header, 4xx are failures due to the nature of the client request (so can be fixed by the client changing what they are doing), 5xx are server errors that can only be resolved server side

Comment: Thanks for the information. I need to rethink whether WCF Rest is the f/w I choose in light of AlioStads comments. However, your input has been valuable in helping me decide.

Answer (score 0):

There's something missing here that needs to be said.

WCF Rest may not be able to provide all functionality of REST protocol, but it is able to facilitate REST protocol for existing WCF services. So if you decide to provide some sort of REST support on top of the current SOAP/Named pipe protocol, it's the way to go if the ROI is low.

Hand rolling full blown REST protocol maybe ideal, but not always economical. In 90% of my projects, REST api is an afterthought. Wcf comes in quite handy in that regard.

Comment: Also, if you want context aware behavior for Wcf REST for HTTP context, it is highly customisable. One example is XML/JSON switching. http://robbincremers.me/2012/01/05/wcf-rest-service-with-xml-json-response-format-according-to-content-type-header/ This post describes how the format can be switched using the content-type header. Again, I agree it's not ideal, but it's not exactly all doom and gloomy.